# Multiple Entity Managers not working Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, entitymanager

I want to use multiple entity manager but it is not working.

**config.yml**

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
       default_connection: default
       connections:
        default:
         driver: pdo_mysql
         host: '%database_host%'
         port: '%database_port%'
         dbname: '%database_name%'
         user: '%database_user%'
         password: '%database_password%'
         charset: UTF8             
        abc_1819:
         driver: pdo_mysql
         host: '%database_host%'
         port: '%database_port%'
         dbname: '%database_name1819%'
         user: '%database_user%'
         password: '%database_password%'
         charset: UTF8

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
           default:
               connection: default
               mappings:
                   AppBundle:  ~
           abc_1819:
               connection: abc_1819
               mappings:
                   Units:
                     is_bundle: false
                     type: annotation
                     dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/AppBundle/Entity'
                     prefix: 'AppBundle\Entity\Units'
```

If i use doctrine commands

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --connection=abc_1819
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force --em=abc_1819
```

it working fine and create the database and table

**UnitsController**
In the controller default manager working by all methods

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
$entityManager =  $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
```

but the **abc_1819** manager not working by using any of methods

```
$entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('abc_1819');
$entityManager =  $this->get('doctrine.orm.abc_1819_entity_manager');
```

it show the following error why ?

**Oops! An Error Occurred**

**The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".**

Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

I find the **issue** when i run project using

```
php bin/console server:run
```

it is working fine
But when i try to use **http://localhost/abc/web/units/** then its not working

Comment: What's the under the hood error message you're getting from php?

Comment: It show 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: That's the server error, not the underlying PHP error - try having a look at your log files

Comment: Yeah, i know it is server error, but it comes when i try to get second manager $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('abc_1819'), if i use default $this->getDoctrine()->getManager(), it working fine

Comment: Tweak localhost server configuration to run in development mode, not production.  I'm guessing your server error is actually coming from something completely unrelated.  Development mode will make it clear what is happening.

Comment: Thanks, let me check